# Dont see sql window and filters window in PGadmin

Tags: pgadmin

can somebody tell me why I dont see sql window and filters window in PGAdmin?
I accidentaly clicked on some btn which separate window with result from the parent window and then I clicked to maximize btn. Now I do not see sql or filter window

[image]